# Windows 10 x64. Unable to hear sound on laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers, sound-card, volume-mixer

I am using Windows 10, and I only have one sound output system which is my Realtek speaker. I can change the sound volume in the volume mixer but can't hear any sound (out of the left speaker). I have fixed the balance in 'Properties' of the playback device. I updated the driver, then reinstalled the driver but still couldn't hear any sound. Could you kindly suggest any solutions?

The system was working fine; it just started to act like this yesterday when I realised the total volume was acting a bit odd.

Comment: Has the system *always* been like this, or has *something* changed prior to this issue?? More info needed. Edit the question, don't comment.

Comment: if this started this morning try a system restore to yesterday if it was a configuration or driver seting this will fix it

Comment: I tried this but not working it says windows updated 10 days ago you can not use this option (recovery to previous version).